# Find a basis $B$ for $\mathbb R^2$ such that $(1, 2)_B = (3, 5)_{ \mathcal E_2}$ and $(3, 4)_B = (2, 3)_{\mathcal E_2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\mathcal E_i$ is the standard basis and $[x]_{\mathcal E_i}$ is the coordinate vector of $x$ with respect to the standard basis.

$[3, 5]_{\mathcal E_2} \implies (3, 5) = 3e_1 + 5e_2 \implies [3, 5]_{\mathcal E_2} = (3, 5)$.

$[2, 3]_{\mathcal E_2} \implies (2, 3) = 2e_1 + 3e_2 \implies [2, 3]_{\mathcal E_2} = (2, 3)$.

Given:

$[1, 2]_B = (3, 5) \implies (1, 2) = 3a + 5b$

$[3, 4]_B = (2, 3) \implies (3, 4) = 2a + 3b$

So

$(1, 2) – (3, 4) = (-2, -2) = a + 2b$ and $(-2, -2) – 2b = a$

Then

$(3, 4) = 2a + 3b \implies (3, 4) = 2[(-2, -2) – 2b] + 3b \implies (3, 4) = (-4, -4) – 2b + 3b → (7, 8) = b$

and

$a = (-2, -2) – 2(7, 8) = (-2, -2) + (-14, -16) = (-16, -18)$ so that

$B = \{(-16, -18), (7, 8)\}$.

I just can't seem to get change of basis problems correct. Does this one work? No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you set this up incorrectly. Letting the basis $B = \left\{a, b \right\}$, the conditions give

$\begin{align*}
a + 2b &= (3, 5) \\
3a + 4b &= (2, 3)
\end{align*}$

and solving for $a$ and $b$ here should give you the correct basis.